# NetException in Lidgren Framework

Tags: c#, networking, monogame, lidgren

What make when happens Lidgren.Network.NetException: "This message has already sent! Use NetPeer.SendMessage() to send multiple recipients efficiently" ?

```
                                else if (CounfOfPlayers == 1)
                            {
                                Player2Connection = inc.SenderConnection;
                                Console.WriteLine(Player2Connection.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                                CounfOfPlayers++;
                                Console.WriteLine("Accepted second player");
                                outmsg.Write((byte)PacketType.RDY);
                                Server.SendMessage(outmsg, Player1Connection, NetDeliveryMethod.ReliableOrdered);
                                Server.SendMessage(outmsg, Player2Connection, NetDeliveryMethod.ReliableOrdered);
                            }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: check edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send each `NetOutgoingMessage` once.

You should use `NetClient.CreateMessage()` to create every instance according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/lidgren-network-gen3/nFA7CAgnwco).